# How to receive big files in a server over UDP?

Tags: java, udp, client-server

I have to send any size file from a client to a server using UDP. I send the datagrams in byte arrays. I split the file and send the datagrams. I know the server receives the datagrams but my problem is on how to put the datagrams in a File again. This is my code for the Client (I'll just put the code that splits and sends the file, I used JavaFX for the client).
Thank you all in advance.

```
private void sendFile(ActionEvent event) {
    ArrayList<byte[]> listDatagrams;
    DatagramSocket socket = null;
    try {
        socket = new DatagramSocket();            
        String serverName = "localhost";
        InetAddress IPserver;
        int serverPort = 6789;
        byte[] data;
        DatagramPacket request;

        IPservidor = InetAddress.getByName(serverName);

        data = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());           

        listDatagrams = splitFile(data);                                  
        for(byte[] datagrama : listDatagrams){
            request= new DatagramPacket(datagrama, datagrama.length, IPserver, serverPort );
            socket.send(request);
        }

        try { 
            fileOuputStream.write(respuesta.getData());
        } finally {
            fileOuputStream.close();
        }          
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        System.out.println("SocketException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOException: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (socket != null) {
            socket.close();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the method I used to split the File:

```
public ArrayList<byte []> splitFile(byte[] file){
    ArrayList<byte[]> data = new ArrayList<>();
    double nPartitions;
    byte[] partition= new byte[MAX];
    if(file.length>MAX){
        nPartitions =Math.ceil(file.length/MAX);
        for(int i=0; i<=nPartitions; i++)
            for(int j=0; j<MAX; j++){
                if(i==0){
                    if(j==file.length-1)
                        break;
                        partition[j]=file[j];                        
                }else if(i==1){
                    if((j+MAX)==file.length-1){
                        break;
                    }else{
                        partition[j]=file[(j+MAX)];
                    }
                }else{
                    if((j+MAX)>=file.length-1)
                        break;
                    partition[j]=file[(i*(MAX+1))+j];                        
                }
            }
            data.add(partition);
        }
    }     
    return data;
}
```

And the code for the server:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    DatagramSocket socket = null;
    ArrayList<DatagramPacket> data= new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        int serverPort= 6789;

        socket = new DatagramSocket(serverPort);

        byte[] buffer;
        buffer = new byte[5000];

        while (true) {
            DatagramPacket request;
            request= new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
            socket.receive(request);
            //I add the datagramas to an array list but I am not sure how to re arrenge them into a File. The server should always be on and be able to receive a second file if I want to
            data.add(request);

        }
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        System.out.println("SocketException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOException: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (socket != null) {
            socket.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I know TCP is better but this is for school so

Comment: You need to create your own application layer protocol.

Comment: So then there is nothing to do in the server side? Thx

Comment: You will need implement it on both server and client.

Comment: I'm just thinking this aloud: you can maybe create a Header for each file which would be sent before the actual byte array chunks, containing the size of the file, for example `{size: 8192}`, the 1st packet would always be the header containing the size, and then upon reception you would just append the bytes to a byte array until the file is complete. although since this is UDP, are we sure there won't be packet loss? if so, maybe you should define a set of control bytes which would define the beginning and end of the file in the packets.